# "IndexError: list index out of range" in SVM classifier using python

Tags: python-2.7, classification, svm, indexoutofrangeexception, index-error

I have problem about my code, here are my code lists

```
import os
os.getcwd()
from SimpleCV import EdgeHistogramFeatureExtractor, HueHistogramFeatureExtractor, MorphologyFeatureExtractor
from SimpleCV.MachineLearning import *
from SimpleCV.ImageClass import Image, ImageSet, ColorSpace
edgeExtractor = EdgeHistogramFeatureExtractor(20) 
hueExtractor = HueHistogramFeatureExtractor(10) 
morphoExtractor = MorphologyFeatureExtractor()
extractorsList = [edgeExtractor, hueExtractor, morphoExtractor]
svm = SVMClassifier(extractorsList)
tree = TreeClassifier(extractorsList, flavor='Boosted')
naiveBayes = NaiveBayesClassifier(extractorsList)
trainPaths = ['C:\\Users\\abi\\Documents\\program coba\\ImageTrain', 'C:\\Users\\abi\\Documents\\program coba\\ImageTest']
trainPaths = ['C:\\Users\\abi\\Documents\\program coba\\ImageTrain\\Positive1', 'C:\\Users\\abi\\Documents\\program coba\\ImageTrain\\Negative1']
classes = ['Negative', 'Positive']
svm.train(trainPaths, classes, savedata="mydata.txt", verbose=False)
testPaths = ['C:\\Users\\abi\\Documents\\program coba\\ImageTest\\Positive1', 'C:\\Users\\abi\\Documents\\program coba\\ImageTest\\Negative1']
print "SVM:", svm.test(testPaths, classes, verbose=False) # [good, bad, confusion]

edgeExtractor = EdgeHistogramFeatureExtractor(20)
svm = SVMClassifier(extractorsList)

listImages = ImageSet()
   for p in ['C:\\Users\\abi\\Documents\\program coba\\NewImages\\coba']: 
        listImages += ImageSet(p)

   for image in listImages:
        className = svm.classify(image)
        image.drawText(className,25,25,fontsize=60)       
listImages.show()
```

After that I get some problem like these

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abi\Documents\program coba\imnew", line 28, in <module>
    className = svm.classify(image)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SimpleCV\MachineLearning\SVMClassifier.py", line 153, in classify
       featureVector.extend([self.mClassNames[0]])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

There is IndexError massage, but I don't know what code is wrong. Now I use Python 2.7.3. Help me, please

Answer (score 0):

`svm` gets initialized twice.  The second time, you skip `svm.train()`, and that's why `self.mClassNames[0]` is empty.

[`mClassNames`](https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV/blob/master/SimpleCV/MachineLearning/SVMClassifier.py#L333) is populated by the `classes` argument in:

```
svm.train(trainPaths, classes, savedata="mydata.txt", verbose=False)`
```

Just remove the second `svm = SVMClassifier(extractorsList)` and that should resolve the `IndexError`.

Note, however, that according to the [documentation](https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV/blob/master/SimpleCV/MachineLearning/SVMClassifier.py#L317), you have your `classes` order out of alignment with the order of image paths in `trainPaths`:

> images - the order of the paths or imagesets must be in the same order as the class type.
>   - Note all image classes must be in seperate directories.
>   - The class names must also align to the directories.

This suggests `classes` should be changed to follow `trainPaths`:

```
trainPaths = ['C:\\Users\\abi\\Documents\\program coba\\ImageTrain\\Positive1', 
              'C:\\Users\\abi\\Documents\\program coba\\ImageTrain\\Negative1']
classes = ['Positive', 'Negative']
```

You also may need to have the `classes` strings match the image directory strings exactly.  The comment in the source code is somewhat ambiguous.   You also define `trainPaths` twice for some reason.